# Mail API - send message with no port attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I started testing Mail API; All examples I could see require to know port to send a message; and I am just wondering is there a way to send email with Mail API if you don't know port but recipient email only? If so I would be glad to see some snippets in this direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are default ports for all the standard email protocols.  If your mail server is using the default port (and almost all do), you don't need to specify the port.

But it sounds like you want to find the mail server to use to send to a particular recipient.  That's a completely different issue.

Comment: No, I just want to send message to any email; you mean port like 25 etc is the port each email server should have?